# How to display address in gmaps4rails_infowindow Rails 3.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, gmaps4rails

I am having only name, lat and lng column in my database. When I display the info window for a particular marker. I need to display address instead of lat and lng. How can this be done
Currently I am display in name, lat and lng

In model I have the following code

```
acts_as_gmappable :lat => "lat", :lng => "lng"

def gmaps4rails_infowindow
  "#{self.name}, #{self.lat}, #{self.lng}"
end
```

In controller

```
def map
  @taxi = Taxi.find(params[:id])
  @json = @taxi.to_gmaps4rails
end
```

In views

```
<%= gmaps({
        "map_options" => { "zoom" => 15, "auto_adjust" => false, "center_latitude" => @taxi.lat, "center_longitude" => @taxi.lng},
        "markers"     => { "data" => @json }
        })
%>
```

The link I followed is [here](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for reverse geocoding which is not included in the gem.

You could do this with geocoder and put the result in 'gmaps4rails_infowindow'